# Just update/insert into DB when there are no errors (@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED))

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

I have a Business class that calls to 6 services. Depending the DTO is treated every moment, a different service is called.

Theoretically every time the business class is called it will call to these 6 services.

I want that only if there are no errors in these 6 services the updates that are done meanwhile are commited into the database.

In case there are errors no commit must be done into database.

Theoretically I have planned in applying this to the Business class that calls to the 6 services and to the 6 services that are called:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
```

Is this Ok?Would you do in a different way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This sounds exactly like what you want to do.

Assuming that each of the 6 services throws an exception if something goes wrong.

You can test this by putting breakpoints into your 6 services, then check in the debugger's stacktrace for the transaction advice and check that all 6 services use the same transaction object (they should). If you then trigger an exception in one of the services, the transaction should be marked for rollback.